# WP-theme Inspiro - trying to set hero image and hero block to fill all screens responsively?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

WP-theme Inspiro light by WP Zoom

Extra css

Knowing no code what so ever, I´m trying to set an image size 2000px x 764px (landscape) to display in full width, on desktop or mobile.

Now... I need to tell the header image to resize to 100% width and I need the header block to follow this behavior.

is there anyone that might be able to help me with this?

Berit, Sweden

dis da im

[on the mountain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVEW.png)

Since I´m a total noobe coding, no use describing the hours I but in to this task.